# Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: codeigniter

I making a login in codeigniter and just got an error

```
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 540**
```

I opened up the url_helper.php & these are the lines I got

```
switch($method)
{
    case 'refresh':
       header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
       break;
    default:
       header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
       break;
}
exit;
}
```

Can anyone offer suggestion of what I need to do ??

Answer (score 1):

Check the controller file you are trying to access.

i think there is a new line character in the beginning of the controller php file you are trying to access. there should not be any characters before the first `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same problem as the OP. I discovered that the base URL in my config/config.php file, around line 26, was not encoded properly. After fixing this, the error stopped. I'm not sure how it was even working at all with the base URL not encoded properly, as I was only getting the error message on redirect from another controller, but that's how I solved the problem.